# jquery load() or innerHtml does not place content inside the target element

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

I am calling the ajax method like so:

```
$("#headerTemplate").load('my-url');
```

headerTemplate is the id of the main div. the fetched content is composed of multiple divs.  When I inspect using chrome devtools, the fetched divs are not inside the main div, but below it. How can I make sure they remain contained in this div, so that the fetched content does not over flow out of bounds?

Comment: According to `jQuery` documentation, `.load()` method has one only necessary parameter and two that can be omitted: `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`, so this is not a problem. Can you provide an example code?

Comment: As of my understanding load ONLY loads INTO target selector. If later you have elements outside, you may what to check your loaded data for errors in HTML syntax that might cause this. It would be useful to see sample data and [mre]

Comment: try this `$("#headerTemplate").load(window.location.href + " #headerTemplate");`

Comment: @ikiK what ????